# Solr match phrase only when field contains nothing else

Tags: solr

How do I get Solr to only match a field with a given phrase and nothing else? e.g. `myfield:"contact lens"` should match `contact lenses` but not `soft contact lenses`?

Edit: Note in the above example that I still need the phrase to be stemmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For exact matches you can have `myfield` to be of type `String` and you can use wild cards to search. This means exact phrase match and case match.

You can also use the `WhitespaceTokenizerFactory`, then stem it using `PorterStemFilterFactory` and then use the `PositionFilterFactory`.

Comment: "KeywordTokenizerFactory: This tokenizer treats the entire text field as a single token." Presumably this makes stemming impossible?

Comment: Yup thats right. After having a closer look at the example I figured it out. I will edit my answer.

Comment: The edit is close but not exact, e.g. `myfield:"algorithm"` will match `"alorithmic complexity"` because the algorithm token is in the right position. I think I'm going to index an extra field containing the number of tokens so that I can write my query like `myfield:"algorithm" AND num_words:1`. Although there is some pre-processing needed in the code, I think this is the least hacky method.

Comment: I found another method here also, that adds left and right tokens during analysis (e.g. replace `algorithm` with `AAAAA algorithm ZZZZZ`) so that you can search for left/right/full match. A bit too hacky for me but may be useful for others: http://robotlibrarian.billdueber.com/boosting-on-exactish-anchored-phrase-matching-in-solr-sst-4/